# Bootstrap-vue Tab style

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm having trouble overriding bootstrap styles in my single file component when using bootstrap-vue

My file looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <b-tabs pills vertical>
    <b-tab title="This title" title-item-class="mytab" acitve>
      Some tab
    </b-tab>
    <b-tab title="This title 2" title-item-class="mytab">
      Some other tab
    </b-tab>
 </b-tabs>
</template>
<script>
export default {}
</script>
<style lang="less" scoped>
  
  .nav-pills .mytab .nav-link:not(.active) {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
  
  .nav-pills .mytab .nav-link {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }
  
  .tab-content > .tab-pane {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0px none;
  }
</style>
```

I can inspect my component and I can see that the "mytab" class is being added to the li parent divs with nav-item classname but the css isn't showing up.

It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/3xwmm1qt/43/ but I'm pretty sure it's because the css is being loaded after the page renders. I'm not 100% about that.

**Updated** I also tried removing the 'scoped' attribute from the style tag and the css still would work. It still doesn't even show up when I inspect the div. I can still see the classname, but in the Rules tab (using FF) there's no styling for my custom classname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the difference between the jsfiddle and your code is that you've written scoped CSS (less):

Here's how you fix it, Remove the scoped from style:

```
<style lang="less">

  .nav-pills .mytab .nav-link:not(.active) {
    background-color: red !important;
  }

  .nav-pills .mytab .nav-link {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }

  .tab-content > .tab-pane {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0px none;
  }
</style>
```

Scoped means that the css code will only work in this element and vue will try to do it only for the classes attached to the elements which have the class you tried to override while not being scoped means that it'll do it for the entire document hence will override bootstrap's css.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and it still didn't work. :(

Comment: I thought it was a bug in bootstrap-vue but they are just importing the bootstrap4 css

Comment: i guess the code snippet you provided didn't have </style>'s last angle bracket

Comment: yeah that was a typo when creating the question

Comment: what are you using to bundle?

Comment: webpack. I used the standard webpack template with vue-cli. I didn't change any of the default setup

Comment: try using css directly instead of less?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167666/discussion-between-lmcadory-and-daksh-miglani).